# USB 3 port is recognized as USB2 on acer predator helios 300 Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, usb, 22.04

I have an acer predator helios 300 laptop (PH317-53) with 3 usb and 1 usb type c ports. The problem is that while 2 ports are recognized as USB 3 ports 2 other ports are recognized as USB2. The color of all the ports is blue.
lsusb shows this:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: The USB2.0 bus can be for internal connections like webcam. Bus != port.

Answer (score 2):

All your USB 3.0 ports are connected to one USB 3.0 hub.

There is nothing to worry about. You can check it by plugging a device to each of the ports and checking to which hub it is connected.

Answer (score 2):

1. Like ChanganAuto said, Bus and ports are different ideas.
2. One USB 3.0 physical port is essentially connected to a USB 3.0 hub and a USB 2.0 hub at the same time. There are 2 different functions on one single port.
3. If you want to inspect ports, insert some USB 2.0/USB 3.0 devices and run
   command "lsusb -t"
4. Take my Computer for example, it has a lot(10) of
   ports but it only has 2 buses, one is USB 2.0 and the other is USB 3.0.

---

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 10000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 23, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 24, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=pl2303, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 26, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 26, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=usbfs, 480M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 12: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 12: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
```